# How to set equal distance between header elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, padding

I'm using the justify-content:space-between to horizontally distribute all elements equally across my header. This works fine until I add **padding-right:20px** to my nav links. It shifts my header h2 element to the right, making it uneven. How do I keep the padding but have my elements equally aligned? Help appreciated, thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/2fr3L8zh/14/

**HTML**

```
<header>
 <div id="header-wrapper">
  <nav>
   <a>Projects</a>
   <a>About</a>
   <a>Contact</a>
  </nav>

 <h2>EMMANUEL OJIJI</h2>
 <p>SOCIAL MEDIA HERE</p>
 </div>
</header>

<section id="intro">
<div id="intro-wrapper">
<h1>I'm Lorem Ipsum — a Birmingham -based Visual Designer with a passion and 
a firm belief in considered and meaningful design.</h1>
</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
height: 100px;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
}

#header-wrapper {
width: 90%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
}

nav a {
padding-right: 20px;
}

#intro {
height: 90vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

#intro-wrapper {
display: flex;
text-align: center;
width: 50%;
}

#intro-wrapper h1 {
font-weight: 700;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-size: 2.2em;
line-height: 60px;
color: #333;
}
```

Comment: What is the intention here? You've made the links wider so naturally everything else shift over.

Comment: @Paulie_D "How do I keep the padding but still have my elements equally aligned?", in other words, is there any way I can make the links padding not affect the rest of my content?

Comment: Does adding margin-left: -20px to the H2 bump it back into place?

Comment: @circusdei It shifts it a little back to the left, but it is still not centred.

Comment: So let me see if i get it righ, you want your `<nav>`, `<h2>` and `<p>` well distributed on the header right?

Comment: looks okay : https://jsfiddle.net/2fr3L8zh/28/ where is the trouble ?

Comment: @G-Cyr Technically it is okay, but in comparison to the text underneath, it is not centred

Comment: section and header wrap do not have same width (i gave margin to the 90% element), it might be part of your issue. You can give equal width to the header element and reset text align to each. https://jsfiddle.net/2fr3L8zh/30/ added some bg to show center and borders too. Is this what you tried to do ?

Comment: @G-Cyr Thank you very much. Works perfectly. Do you mind doing a quick explanation of why the flex:1 addition and margin auto works?

Comment: margin:auto is to center the header-wrapper element (it is 90% width and section covers 100%'s width) . flex:1; is to spray your 3 flex children with the width.(flex does the calculation)

Comment: @G-Cyr Ah makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the padding for the last element of the navigation:

```
nav a:not(:last-child)
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  ;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#header-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#intro {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#intro-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}

#intro-wrapper h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <nav>
      <a>Projects</a>
      <a>About</a>
      <a>Contact</a>
    </nav>

    <h2>EMMANUEL OJIJI</h2>
    <p>SOCIAL MEDIA HERE</p>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="intro">
  <div id="intro-wrapper">
    <h1>I'm Lorem Ipsum — a Birmingham -based Visual Designer with a passion and a firm belief in considered and meaningful design.</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```